# Names determined by a condition

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $M$ be a c.t.m., $\mathbb{P}\in M$ be a poset, $p\in\mathbb{P}$ be a condition, and $\tau\in M$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-name. We can define a relation "*$p$ determines $\tau$*" recursively as follows: $p$ determines $\tau$ iff for all $(\sigma,q)\in\tau$, $p\perp q\,\lor\,(p\le q\,\land\,p$ determines $\sigma)$. It is clear that if $p$ determines $\tau$ then $\tau_G$ is the same set for every generic filter $G$ such that $p\in G$. Also, it is possible to define a $\mathbb{P}$-name $\tau$ that is determined by each of two conditions $p$, $q$, but $\tau_G\neq\tau_H$ whenever $G,H$ are generic filters such that $p\in G$ and $q\in H$.

I have two questions.

1. If $\tau_G$ is the same set for every generic $G$ containing $p$, is
   it necessary that $p$ determines $\tau$?
2. If $p$ determines $\tau$ and $G$ is a generic filter such that $p\in
   G$, does it follow that $\tau_G\in M$?

Comment: By restricting the forcing to $p$, both of your questions can be approached by assuming that $p=1_\Bbb P$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the hint. So the answer to first question is "no", as we can take name $\tau=\{(\emptyset,q)\!:q\in A\}$ where $A$ is a maximal antichain not containing $p$. Then $\tau$ is not determined by $p$ but $\tau_G$ is always $\{\emptyset\}$. As for the second question, "$1$ determines $\tau$" means just that $\tau=\check x$ for some $x\in M$. So if $p=1$ then the answer is "yes". For general $p$, the answer is still "yes", and it can be proved by induction on the rank of the name. Am I right?